# Django: How to check if the user left all fields blank (or to initial values)?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I know `is_valid()` on a bounded form checks if all required data is entered. This is not what I want. I want to check if *any* field was filled on the form.

Any ideas?

**Elaborating:**

I want to give the user the choice of not filling in the form at all. However, if they attempt to fill it in (ie: changed a value in a field from it's initial value---usually empty value), I want to validate it.

The view would be something like this:

```
def get_opinion(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = OpinionForm(request.POST)
        if form_is_blank(f):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thank_you_anyway'))
        elif f.is_valid():
            #Process here
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thanks_for_participating'))
    else:
        initial = {'weekday': date.today().strftime('%A')}
        f = OpinionForm(initial=initial)

    return render_to_response(
        'get_opinion.html',
        {'form': f,},
        RequestContext(request)
    )
```

What I want is the `form_is_blank()` part.

Comment: You should put more of a distinct use case for this. If you just care about having at least one field filled in then that sounds like something that should happen client side with some javascript.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks for the suggestion. I elaborated with some code.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Guess I have to answer my own question.

Apparently, there's an undocumented `Form` function: `has_changed()`

```
>>> f = MyForm({})
>>> f.has_changed()
False
>>> f = MyForm({'name': 'test'})
>>> f.has_changed()
True
>>> f = MyForm({'name': 'test'}, initial={'name': 'test'})
>>> f.has_changed()
False
```

So this would do nicely as the replacement for `form_is_blank()` (reverted of course).

Comment: What if you want to save the form if it isn't blank? The `has_changed` method wouldn't help there, would it?

Comment: Why do you duplicate the `f = MyForm({})` case?

Answer (score 4):

To get this functionality work for subset of Forms used in the actual <form> tag you also need to define

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def full_clean(self):
        if not self.has_changed():
            self._errors = ErrorDict()
            return

        return super(YourForm, self).full_clean()
```

so when the user is prompted to fix validation errors it doesnt display errors from the forms which you want to validate only if some value isn't blank (or default).

Answer (score 3):

You should set required=False for all fields in the form and override the `clean` method to do custom validation. See [the current documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for more.

Comment: For my particular use case, I have multiple forms in the view.  If the user starts filling out one of the forms, then I want certain fields to be required.

Answer (score 1):

If you have put `required=True` in your forms field or in the model `blank=False` so `is_valid()` should return False.

Answer (score 0):

Use [modelformset_Factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet) and pass your custom formset to it